# How to configure a consumer's generated error queue to use the same routing key as the normal queue?

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, masstransit

Let's say that I have a consumer:

```
public class TestConsumer : IConsumer<TestMessage> {
...
```

that is configured to use a routing key using:

```
cfg.ReceiveEndpoint("test_queue", e=> {
  e.Bind<TestMessage>(x => {
    x.RoutingKey = "test_routing_key"
  });
});
```

It creates a queue called "test_queue" and binds it to the exchange with the routing key "test_routing_key". If the consumer catches an unhandled exception it also creates an error queue called "test_queue_error" and binds it to the 'Fault-TestMessage' exchange with no routing key.

How can I configure the generated error queue to be bound to the fault exchange with a chosen routing key?

I wasn't able to find out how to do this in the documentation. If it's not possible, then how can I differentiate between errors thrown by different consumers for the original exchange?

Comment: I assume when you say "_error" queue - you mean dead letter queue, right?
When defining DLQ in rabbit, if you want to use single exchange for all DLQ - this is where routing key will help as well. Or using a dedicated exchange for each queue. Both approaches will work.
But it seems masstransit is not really flexible to tune this up and uses its own _error queue for that.

Answer (score 0):

The queue named `test_queue_error` is based off the receive endpoint name (same as the queue name), and queues do not have routing keys. Only exchange bindings have routing keys. It would not make sense to have error queue "binding" with a routing key since the *_error* queue maps 1:1 with a receive endpoint queue name.